# I keep getting the same error message "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ngCordovaProvider <- $ngCordova <- AppCtrl"

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I keep getting the same error over and over again:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ngCordovaProvider <- $ngCordova <- AppCtrl.
```

I included the cordova jsfile in my index.html (`<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>`).

In my controllers.js file I included the dependencies as well:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $ionicActionSheet, $timeout, $ngCordova, $cordovaCapture) {
```

If anyone could help me, it would mean a lot!

Comment: Can you check in browser there is ng-cordova.js or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `ngCordova` doesn't provide a service called `$ngCordova`. As far as I can see from the documentation, there really is no such service.